# Can't find the error in this small program

Tags: c++, runtime-error

I have a very specific issue relating to C++ in a book I am currently studying. The Book is called 'Programming Principles and Practices using C++' and the author is the creator himself.

My issue basically is that the book asks you to find the serious error that is in this very small program (for practice purposes of course) but I am not sure if what I found to be an 'error' is the error or even considered an error for that matter.

Here is the small snippet of code:

```
template<typename Iterator>
Iterator high(Iterator first, Iterator last)
{
    Iterator high = first;
    for (Iterator p = first; p != last; ++p) {
        if (*high < *p) high = p;
    }

    return high;
}

double* get_from_jack(int* count)
{
    *count = 3;
    return new double[3]{ 1.1, 2.2, 3.3 };
}

vector<double>* get_from_jill()
{
    return new vector<double>{ 1.1, 2.2, 3.3 };
}

void fct()
{
    int jack_count = 0;
    double* jack_data = get_from_jack(&jack_count);
    vector<double>* jill_data = get_from_jill();

    double* jack_high = high(jack_data, jack_data + jack_count);
    vector<double>& v = *jill_data;
    double* jill_high = high(&v[0], &v[0] + v.size());

    cout << "Jack high: " << *jack_high << endl
        << "Jill high: " << *jill_high << endl;

    delete[] jack_data;
    delete jill_data;
}
```

The 'error' that I found is that you could pass two random memory addresses into the 'high' function and it would not perform correctly. So my question here is am I correct or am I missing something else? I am still studying C++ and programming so this is to help with my knowledge, I will not gain anything else from this other than knowledge.

Edit: As some users have stated, it is terrible code but it shouldn't be difficult to realise that was the author's intentions. The book's teaching method is to slowly go from sloppy code to much better code using more advanced techniques.

Comment: This is insanely bad C++. Please find a different source to learn the language than this. Pointers in particular are tricky and very advanced topic. Raw memory management like this pretty much does not exist in modern C++ (or rather, should not be used at all).

Comment: I wouldn't dwell on that particular artificial problem for long. It won't teach you much - and you are very unlikely to stumble across code like this in the real world. It's designed by the author to be horrible. Success :-)

Comment: I wanted to be sure that was the main error he was referring to. I know this is terrible code but its very simplified as you can see. The point of it is to introduce the reader to Iterators I guess. The book has proven to be effective for me so far, so I would have to disagree with finding a different source to learn from. I think this small bit of code has you believing its a bad source but like Ted said, it was intended to be bad.

Comment: @Pembo97 Why would you teach using bad examples? There are plenty of good (and more importantly real-world) examples of common issues with both iterators and pointers. Artificial examples like this one do not resemble real-world code and would not help you understand the fundamental and common issues with both concepts (pointers and iterators). Good examples start with an actual problem to solve, typicial way of solving it and using that code they demonstrate what often goes wrong. This code does nothing, solves no problem and is horribly written to top it off. I hope the rest is not the same.

Comment: At the end of each chapter, you are given some good exercises that do actually make you think to solve problems. I'm quite sure this book is mainly aimed at beginners too so giving 100% real world problems to a beginner is probably not the most ideal way of teaching? I don't know, all I know is that the book is fine and this is just a small exercise within the chapter. The code here is bad even I know that, but I think to understand the reasoning of why it is there you may have to read the book before judging it entirely, I don't know. I think I shall take Ted's advice anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious error is if the array or vector has zero size.  <strike>In that case, the first line of the function returns first which when dereferenced is undefined.  It's better to return last when first == last.  That is well defined and standard practice for arrays and vectors but you have to check it and not dereference it.</strike>

```
template<typename Iterator>
Iterator high(Iterator first, Iterator last)
{
    if (first == last) return last;

    Iterator high = first;
    for (Iterator p = first; p != last; ++p) {
        if (*high < *p) high = p;
    }

    return high;
}
```

This line is undefined for zero size vectors - you can't take the zero element of an empty vector:

```
double* jill_high = high(&v[0], &v[0] + v.size());
```

Instead it should be this:

```
std::vector<double>::iterator jill_high = high(v.begin(), v.end());
```

And then you **must** check if the result of high is `jack_data + jack_count` for the array and `v.end()` for the vector since you can't dereference either one.  Instead you can print out "N/A" or something similar.

Comment: If `first == last`, then it doesn't matter whether you `return first` or `return last`. They're the same value.

Answer (score -1):

> The 'error' that I found is that you could pass two random memory addresses into the `high` function and it would not perform correctly.

What is your expectation in this case?

In C++ pointer comparison is well defined only when the pointers refer to elements of the same array (including the pointer to one past the last element). Otherwise that is *undefined behaviour*. For *undefined behaviour* C++ standard doesn't require any particular behaviour, hence *undefined*.